# Method to check array list containing specific string

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have an ArrayList that import records from a database.
Is there any method to check whether the arrayList contains schname that i want to match to another list which is an api?

```
List<PrimaryClass> primaryList = new List<PrimaryClass>(e.Result);
PrimaryClass sc = new PrimaryClass();
foreach (string item in str)
{
    for (int a = 0; a <= e.Result.Count - 1; a++)
    {
        string schname = e.Result.ElementAt(a).PrimarySchool;
        string tophonour = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopHonour;
        string cca = e.Result.ElementAt(a).Cca;
        string topstudent = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopStudent;
        string topaggregate = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopAggregate;
        string topimage = e.Result.ElementAt(a).TopImage;        
        if (item.Contains(schname))
        {
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I have come up with so far, kindly correct any errors that I might have committed. Thanks.

Comment: I would expect that you *actually* have a `List<T>` if it's Silverlight - I thought that didn't support nongeneric collections. Please edit your question to make this clear, along with the *actual* type of data in the list.

Comment: You really should add more information and a code sample if you want quality answers.

Comment: Use generic collection (it's 2011 and half now!) and it will help you a lot

Comment: @Jon ok i added some codes see if it is enough

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this

```
foreach( string row in arrayList){
    if(row.contains(searchString)){
       //put your code here.
    }
}
```

Comment: `ArrayList.Contains` you should always use a built-in method if it exists

Answer (score 9):

How about [`ArrayList.Contains`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.arraylist.contains.aspx)?

Answer (score 4):

Okay, now you've shown that it's actually a `List<T>`, it should be easy with LINQ:

```
if (primaryList.Any(x => item.Contains(x.PrimarySchool))
```

Note that you should really consider using `foreach` instead of a for loop to iterate over a list, unless you *definitely* need the index... and if you're dealing with a list, using the indexer is simpler than calling `ElementAt`.

Comment: where would you put the schname in this if thats the field which I would like to use

Comment: @GJJ: As far as I can see, `schname` isn't a property of the `PrimaryClass` type... you were initializing the *local variable* (not field) `schname` from the `PrimarySchool` property, which is why I used that.

Answer (score 3):

```
// check all types
var containsAnyMatch = arrayList.Cast<object>().Any(arg => arg.ToString() == searchText);

// check strings only
var containsStringMatch = arrayList.OfType<string>().Any(arg => arg == searchText);
```

Comment: Does Silvelight fully support such LINQ?